# Select one of many-to-many matches between data.table dt1$id and dt2$id such that dt1$id and dt2$id are unique in the result set

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have two data.table's dt1 and dt2 with id1 and id2 as the unique key column and I perform an unequal many to many join result set dtR with the matching id1 and id2.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(id1 = c(1:12),a = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),key='id1')
dt2 = data.table(id2 = c(13:24), b = c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),key='id2')
dtR <- dt2[dt1,.(id1,id2,a,b),on=.(b < a)]
```

How do I filter dtR such that id1 is unique in dtR$id1 column and id2 is unique in dtR$id2:

```
data.table(
  id1=c(1,2,5,6,9,10),id2=c(13,14,15,16,17,18))
```

Note that dt1 and dt2 involve millions of rows and high memory, so it should be efficient and copy or loops should be avoided.
Thanks!

I tried iterating over id1, creating an additional column with matched id2 and checking for existing id2, adding the next one. Very time consuming. A SQL solution would also be acceptable as dt1 and dt2 reside in DuckDb.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` grouping solution will be pretty fast.

```
system.time({
  u2 <- unique(sort(dtR$id2))
  avail <- rep(TRUE, length(u2))
  x <- dtR[, m2 := match(id2, u2)][
    , .(
      id2 = {
        m <- m2[which.max(avail[m2])]
        if (avail[m]) {
          avail[m] <- FALSE
          u2[m]
        }  else NULL
      }
    ), id1
  ]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       0

x
#>       id1  id2
#>   1:    1   77
#>   2:    2  188
#>   3:    3  109
#>   4:    4   14
#>   5:    5   47
#>  ---          
#> 983:  996 9472
#> 984:  997 9036
#> 985:  998 9688
#> 986:  999 8646
#> 987: 1000 9066
uniqueN(x[[1]])
#> [1] 987
uniqueN(x[[2]])
#> [1] 987
```

Data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
dt1 = data.table(
  id1 = c(1:1e3),
  a = sample(1:1e2,1e3,replace = T),key='id1')
dt1[,`:=`(alo=a-5,ahi=a+5)]
dt2 = data.table(
  id2 = c(1:1e4), 
  b = sample(1:1e3,1e4,replace = T),key='id2')
dtR <- dt2[dt1,.(id1,id2,a,b),on=.(b < ahi, b>alo)]
```

Comment: Thanks very much, indeed your solution was much faster!

Comment: With 1e5 rows on dt1, 1e6 rows on dt2 and about 1e6 rows on dtR, your code was 0.7" vs. 29 minutes  for the looping code. Now that's an improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Cool question. Not sure how to do it without loops myself. Might want to check how slow the following is:

```
x <- vector("list",nrow(dtR))
last_unique_id1 <- dtR[1,id1]
last_unique_id2 <- dtR[1,id2]
counter = 1
x[[counter]] <- dtR[1,.(id1,id2)]
for(i in 2:nrow(dtR)){
  if(dtR[i,id1] > last_unique_id1 &  dtR[i,id2] > last_unique_id2){
    last_unique_id1 <- dtR[i,id1]
    last_unique_id2 <- dtR[i,id2]
    counter = counter + 1
    x[[counter]] <- dtR[i,.(id1,id2)]
  }

}  
x <- rbindlist(x)
x
#   id1 id2
#1:   1  13
#2:   2  14
#3:   5  15
#4:   6  16
#5:   9  17
#6:  10  18
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had tried something similar. With the following code: see next answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Evan_Friedland for the suggestion. Here is an application of your code:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
dt1 = data.table(
  id1 = c(1:1e3),
  a = sample(1:1e2,1e3,replace = T),key='id1')
dt1[,`:=`(alo=a-5,ahi=a+5)]
dt2 = data.table(
  id2 = c(1:1e4), 
  b = sample(1:1e3,1e4,replace = T),key='id2')
dtR <- dt2[dt1,.(id1,id2,a,b),on=.(b < ahi, b>alo)]
system.time({
  x <- vector("list",nrow(dtR))
  last_unique_id1 <- dtR[1,id1]
  last_unique_id2 <- dtR[1,id2]
  counter = 1
  x[[counter]] <- dtR[1,.(id1,id2)]
  for(i in 2:nrow(dtR)){
    if(dtR[i,id1] > last_unique_id1 &  
       dtR[i,id2] > last_unique_id2){
      last_unique_id1 <- dtR[i,id1]
      last_unique_id2 <- dtR[i,id2]
      counter = counter + 1
      x[[counter]] <- dtR[i,.(id1,id2)]
    }
    
  }  
  x <- rbindlist(x)
})
```

This code took 38" and yielded 83 unique id1 and id2.

The code I tried, below, took 4" and yielded 987 id1 and id2, the remaining 13 id1 were only matched to repeat id2. But this is still slow for table 1000 to 10,000 times bigger.

```
dtc <- copy(dtR)
system.time({
  setkey(dtR,id1)
  for(i in unique(dtR$id1)){
    try({
      uId <- dtR[id1==i,first(id2)]
      dtR[id1==i & id2==uId,keep:=1,mult='first']
      dtR <- dtR[(id1!=i & id2 != uId) | keep==1]
    })
  }})
```